# csvkit - command line csv viewer and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python, csv

Has anyone tried using [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/) in Ubuntu 18.04. I use the command *csvlook* to view csv files from command line. It used to work in other Ubuntu versions but in 18.04 I get error like the following when trying view the

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 252: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876278/python-error-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-u2026 helps.

Comment: could you share the csv file?